# What is Wrong with the Solution to this Discrete Dynamical System?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

I am supposed to solve the discrete dynamical system _k+1=A*x_k, and I have been given both the matrix A and x_O (please see the picture below). I started out by calculating the eigenvalues and then their eigenvectors, so that I have lambda, and could then get the weights for c1 and c2 by putting the eigenvectors on the right-hand side and x_0 on the left-hand side. However, my answer seems to be wrong. Does anyone see where in my calculations I messed up?

[image]

[image]

Many thanks, Nick

Comment: your $v_1$ is wrong ($v_2$ is fine)

Comment: @achillehui Oh, now I see, thanks. But that means that there are no free variables, right? Can I then get an eigenvector?

Comment: $(A-4I)\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac52\\ 0 & -5\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ is equivalent to $y = 0$, so $v_1 \propto \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$